# For which matrix $Q$ does the lyapunov equation have a unique solution?

Tags: stability-theory

Suppose I have the equation
$$A^\top K +KA+Q=0$$
I know that $A$ is stable and $Q$ is symmetric. I want to prove that the solution $K$ to this equation is unique. What constraints should I put on $Q$? How can I prove the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: Are you solving this equation for $K$?

Comment: Yes I am. I will edit the question

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation#Continuous_time), if $A$ is stable, then the equation will have a unique solution for *any* $Q$.